# Make entire DIV block clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script on my site and using jQuery it makes the `variation-value` `div` element clickable.

Unfortunately the areas with the `p` & `div` tags aren't clickable. Is there an easy fix for this?

***jsfiddle example :::*** http://jsfiddle.net/xb4qkdLu/ :::

```
<div class="variation-value">
    <p class="left" style="background:green">left aligned text</p>
    <div class="right" style="background:red">right aligned text</div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you bind events for that.?

Comment: By doing a `$('.variation-value').click(function(){  alert('clicked'); });` you should have the event trigger regardless of what element you click within the whole div. Likely you've got some other code interfering.

Comment: What `<span>` tag? :)

Comment: I would probably be interested in your CSS as well...

Comment: @ne1410s Sorry, I changed it to a `div` while testing.

Comment: Will edit main question shortly with snippet of jQuery - thank you for any help :-)

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you simplify it or recreate the issue on http://jsfiddle.net Where is the click binding on `.variation-value` ?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try get a fiddle sorted :-)

Comment: @Huangism Woop - jsfiddle freshly prepared : http://jsfiddle.net/xb4qkdLu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm seeing in the jsfiddle you posted afterward, is that you are binding the click to the `td` element within the `variation` class (`$('.variation').on('click', 'td', function(event){...`).

Based on what you wrote, and the comment I've left under your original post, hooking a click trigger listener to the `.variation-value'` class would solve this for you (as you've currently got no events tied to it).

If you would like to supplement you original script, you would either have to go around with some CSS "hack", by adding to the css of `p` and `span` within the td the following `pointer-events:none;` (will require some extra IE fine-tuning), or you could also add the other elements within the `td` to the trigger listener.

Code sample:

The CSS would be like (considering normal-case browser):

```
.variation-value > p, .variation-value > div { pointer-events:none; }
```

The Jquery would be:

```
$('.variation-value').on('click', function(event){ ... }
```

Do keep in mind that your `left` element is bound to reset your values list if it is visible (haven't found any trigger set for the `right` element). If you are enabling a click-through effect for all the elements within your `.variation-values`, you are losing the reset-effect bound to the left element. Is that surely what you are looking to achieve? If so, just go wihout the above CSS snippet, and you will have it all function as you would like.

Also just to note, in your HTML markup, you are putting elements in the following hierarchy:

```
div.variation-value
    p[left]
        div[right]
```

You aren't closing your `p` element before adding in the `div` for the right element that is it becomes a child of the `p`. I'm assuming you should've closed the `p` tag to ensure functionality as intended.

Comment: Many many thanks for looking at my issue and such a detailed answer. I'm really not hot with jQuery - can you possibly show me where I should edit my script and with what?

Comment: Yeah, right away, I'll make the necessary changes and post the code.

Comment: Many thanks, @Gabor, I really really appreciate all your help with this - you're a legend! :-D

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Gabor - can you clarify what line number I should use this on `$('.variation-value').on('click', function(event){ ... }` ?

Comment: Line 456 of your jsfiddle instead of the line found there. CSS anywhere at the end of your stylesheet should do.

Comment: It works perfectly in `jsfiddle` but not on my local version :'-(

Comment: Have you got the same library versions running on your local as in jsfiddle (1.7.2 jquery for example)? Is the developer console of the browser showing any errors or warnings?

Comment: It was a huge script & I lost track at one point - fixed it - @Gabor, you are a king - thank you for your help & patience :-D

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hasecbinusr/pctgs5ke/

```
$(document).ready( function(e) {
  $('.variation-value').click(function () {
    alert('You clicked it!');
  });
});
```